# Using Vim with light or white background color scheme

Tags: vim, color-scheme

When using Vim with on a terminal with a light or white background, most color schemes are subtly broken. How can I fix this? Is it possible to use a color scheme which is designed for a light or a white background?

How can I chose a vim colorschemes which uses white/or lightgrey as background color?

Comment: THANK you. It seems like all the colorschemes are tailored towards a black background. Are we the only programmers who like light backgrounds?

Comment: These answers can be sparse on instructions on how to apply the color schemes.  Here is a walkthrough on how to setup a colors and syntax highlighting with vim: https://github.com/sentientmachine/Pretty-Vim-Python

Comment: disagree with the closure finding.  this is actually a very concrete question, in fact one i came here precisely to find answers to.

Comment: I did some searching (the [github colorscheme tag](https://github.com/topics/colorscheme) is useful), here's a bunch that I found reasonable: [vim-colors-plain](https://github.com/andreypopp/vim-colors-plain), [One Half Light](https://github.com/sonph/onehalf/tree/master/vim), [vim-colors-github](https://github.com/cormacrelf/vim-colors-github), [snow](https://github.com/nightsense/snow)

Answer (score 15):

[Solarized](http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized/) For Vim python code files:

[image]

or

[image]

More work has been put into this than your average color scheme.

Comment: That font looks cool, which one it is?

Comment: I'm wondering why Solarized themes are so many times recommended. I used both of them and after a while I feel more tired than when I used white on black or black on white. Solarized to be better should have much higher contrast.

Comment: @sarath It's NovaMono here's the relevant powerline font that'll work with airline too: https://github.com/powerline/fonts/blob/master/NovaMono/NovaMono%20for%20Powerline.ttf

Answer (score 9):

I use [Proton](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2510) on a daily basis. I love it.

Comment: Oh there actually are people using my color theme(s) :) If you have any suggestions, don't hesitate to contact me!

Comment: I didn't even know about Proton, but I'm already using it. I like it a lot! Thanks for making it @Droggl.

Comment: Note that this theme still exists at the above link and works as of May 2019.

Answer (score 6):

I prefer this one:
[habiLight](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1527)

By the way: For an overview of colorschemes available for Vim
see [vimcolorschemetest](http://code.google.com/p/vimcolorschemetest/).
Go to section "Browse by File Type" an select the file type
for which you want to see the examples.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure if it is gauche to suggest one's own color scheme, but I do genuinely prefer to a broad range of light-background schemes that I've tried, whether coding in Python or not: [mayansmoke](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3065).

Example screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

My personal favorite is Elflord.  However you might like pyte, I have tried that and found it to my own liking.  Desert and desert256 are more in the brown range, but you may like those as well. But my best suggestion for you is **earendel**.  Good luck finding the right ones for you, if you need a list of all of them, I think this is where I found mine:

http://www.vim.org/scripts/script_search_results.php?&script_type=color%20scheme&order_by=rating&show_me=20&result_ptr=0

Comment: thanks jim. earendel looks awesome to me =)

Answer (score 1):

I stick with the default colors. The bold yellow is quite horrible (but it might be my consoles fault [(link)](http://img151.imageshack.us/img151/6469/asdff.png)), everything else is very good.

I stick with the default in order to have the same colors everywhere,
and secondly I don't "see" (care) which color is which, but only that colors differ. It's unconscious.

Answer (score 0):

I definitely recommend [this](https://github.com/robertmeta/vim-files) color scheme and configuration. You can just clone this repo in you .vim folder and you're on.

Comment: I suspect what you mean is this `colorscheme`: https://github.com/robertmeta/nofrils